# C# output to .csv file not separating columns on commas

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a C# application that extracts a large amount of data from an SQL database and processes it. I want to output that data to a .csv file, but when I write it to the .csv file and open it, instead of finding my data separated into columns like so:

```
Id       Model    Number of items
10283    D        6
5673     B        4
224      X        2
```

I get:

```
Id,Model,Number of items
10283,D,6
5673,B,4
224,X,2
```

This is the code I use to output the data to a .csv file:

```
using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\test.csv"))
{
    w.WriteLine("Id,Model,Number of items,etc.");
    w.Flush();

    //Products is a list of product, a custom class
    foreach (product p in products)
    {
        //All properties of p shown here are strings
        w.WriteLine(p.id.ToString() + ',' + p.model
            + ',' + p.num.ToString());

        w.Flush();
    }
}
```

I have tried using AppendAllText() and WriteAllText() instead of this method, and using a tab character as a delimiter instead of a comma, but I get the same result.
I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem with google, in fact, when I search for this issue, I get results of people who want to get commas instead of columns in their data, the exact opposite problem to this.

Comment: So do I understand you want it tab delimited?

Comment: No, I want excel to recognise the comma as a delimiter for columns, which, to the best of my knowledge, it should.

Comment: Then you will have to ask an excel question in an excel forum. Excel automatically separates tab separated text into columns for you; if you want it to do the same with commas then you will have to change Excel's options to do so, if it's even possible.

Comment: look up how to use `string.Join()` method

Comment: I copied/pasted your data to a .csv file and opened it in Excel.  It works fine.

Comment: use csvhelper https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ - it will deal with all the nasty quoting issues etc. (thats not why you have a problem tho)

Comment: @Quantic nah, excel should do it automatically, but it has issues with certain versions

Comment: @SteveG Apparently if you create a `.csv` file and open it, excel will import it into columns for you. My comment is slightly incorrect, I've seen that if you *paste* tab-delimited text in, excel will automatically split into columns. But pasting comma-delimited text in it does not. I assumed OP was copying/pasting, not creating a file. Either way, it's still an excel question if they don't want to use `"\t"`.

Comment: @Quantic why would you think he was pasting it in.... he shared code for creating a csv...

Comment: How the file looks when you _open_ it depends on the program you're using to open it, and what you tell that program to do. If the file itself is being generated correctly, then there's no programming question here at all. If you still think there's a programming question here, then please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, and explain precisely what output that code produces and what output you want from that code instead.

Comment: @Manu what version of excel are you using? I know some older versions have trouble opening csv's as you think they should

Comment: A .csv stands for CommaSeparatedValue, not ColumnSeparatedValue. That format is natively recognized by excel and unless you have string columns that contain comma, you don't need to use any quotes. Even with the perfect csv creation you risk the loss of data. Since you need to transfer data from SQL server to excel, you could simply create an excel file using automation and add the data to it using QueryTables.Add or CopyFromRecordset. Or without using Excel automation, you can download and use Epplus library from Codeplex.

Comment: @SteveG Because he pasted tab-delimited text into the question and called them "columns". You are right I was not paying very close attention. He actually wanted to post a screen shot of the Excel application showing it split into actual Excel columns, and not show us tab-delimited text then basically asking, "why is my text separated by commas".

Comment: @SteveG I am using excel 2010

Comment: @Manu http://superuser.com/questions/396469/how-to-control-csv-import-into-excel-2010

Comment: @Quantic Yeah, I'm sorry if it seemed a bit ambiguous. I had seen others use that format to illustrate columns instead of using a screenshot on this site before, so I thought it was the correct/standard way of showing columns

Comment: @Manu thats a fine way to show columns, don't worry about it

Comment: Extract the data from Sql Server then fill it in a Datatable.. then build the .csv file from there first getting the columns names separated by `,` using string.Join() method this can be handled..  then write the columns to a List<T> then do a foreach(DataRow dataRow in yourDataTable.Rows)` build the comma separatd values from the dataRow.ItemArray this is not that difficult

Comment: @MethodMan look at his output example.... he obviously has a CSV created

Comment: then what's the problem.. I think that @Manu needs to read up on what CSV is ..Thanks `Steve G`

Comment: @MethodMan read the question, when he opens it in excel, it isn't breaking up by column....

Comment: if it saves as .csv and he opens it in Excel.. perhaps there is data in the file that has `,` commas with in the actual values any comma's or extra comma's excel will see them as extra columns this seems like common sense to me but we would have to see the entire file not just a few lines to determine if what I am saying is correct

Comment: @MethodMan then you wouldn't see the commas, you would see it populate too many columns.....

Comment: @Manu Sorry for any confusion. Your question is wholly contained to Excel and as we found out has nothing to do with `c#` or `csv`. I assume you've already set your Excel options to handle the csv file correctly as shown in the link by SteveG.

Comment: @SteveG I am aware that I can get it to be correctly split into columns by importing it to a .csv file and choosing the comma as a delimiter, but I would like the output to be split into columns already. If there is some way to do that from within the program so that the user doesn't have to import it every time, I would appreciate it if you told me.

Comment: Actually @SteveG you would get extra columns as well as the data with the comma's would still load I have an existing issue that I have been trying to get the end users to remove comma's and I can totally prove this / reproduce this.. like I am saying it's easier to see the full data then we would both know

Comment: @Manu In more modern versions of excel it does that automatically. I'm not sure if you can set up 2010 to do that or not. It sounds like something you can research though

Comment: how come I can do this and get zero issue but @Manu you are getting issues .. perhaps you should post the full contents of your file so we can all see why you are having this issue..

Comment: "but I would like the output to be split into columns already" -- you would have to write a `.xls` file for that to occur, and doing that from c# is a pain in the butt. You cannot write a text file that has "excel columns" in it, you would have to write an excel file. You can write tab delimited text to a file and have excel interpret it as columns, or write "anything" delimited text to it and then tell excel what the delimiters are. But they are just strings in the file; excel columns are specially coded into `.xls` files and you cannot make your own with strings in a text file.

Comment: @Manu as Quantic said, there are other ways of created excel files other than CSV's, you can load up some com objects and do it programmatically too if thats an option.... it is more of a pain in the butt. My best suggestion is determine what version of excel the people you're writing this for use... if it's newer, just keep it as a CSV

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for one, I recommend putting quotes around the text... something like

```
w.WriteLine('"' + p.id.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\",\"" + 
    p.model.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + ',' + 
    p.num.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""));
```

Comment: I enclosed each item (p.id.ToString(), p.model, and pp.num.ToString()), and it added double quotes around my values except for the first one (p.id), but still no columns

Comment: you need to understand how CSV works this is not that difficult also you do not need to wrap double quotes around the values unless the data that you are retrieving has quotes in them

Comment: Often you don't know which columns contain quotes in them until it's already in production. Same thing with commas. You should probably just escape them on all columns like this answer shows. Especially considering it's not that difficult or unreasonable to expect. +1

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit too late but I encountered the same issue. I fixed it and it's a dumb issue. I forgot that I was coding in German server/instance, so the delimiters they are using in CSV is actually semicolon, not comma. Try changing your delimiter to semicolon - it will separate your headers into different columns when you open the CSV file via Excel.